# How to generate X509 certificate with non repudiation Key Usage

Tags: c#, openssl, certificate, x509, signature

To sign my XML document correctly, I need to do this with a self-signed certificate which contain "non repudiation" key usage.

I search on internet how I can do this with Makecert but apparently is impossible and I don't found how I can do this with OpenSSL.

Someone can help me please ?

Thank you !

EDIT : Maybe I can create it by code ? I'm using C# !

Comment: Bouncy Castle is far better an option.

Comment: Ok, I will look at this !